# Python class service

Tags: python, python-2.7, singleton

I have a class called `Camera` which is initializing the webcam on Linux using Python, but I have a problem with that class. I want to use that class in multiple programs. I made the class a singleton. When I access the class multiple times in same program it works perfectly, it returns a single instance. But when I access the class from other program it create other instance. For example:

```
class Camera():
    __new__():
    .....
    .....
    print "__new__ called"
    __init__():
       get_frame();
       print "__instance created"

c1 = Camera()
c2 = Camera()
Results:
__new__ called
__instance created
__new__ called
```

But I want to access the class from multiple program like:

```
main1.py
main2.py 
main3.py
```

I want to access this class from multiple programs and I want the class to initialize just once and then return same instance to every program calling this class.

Is there any way that I create a program or service of `Camera` class and I run the class individually and I will access the elements of class from other programs?

Please give an example of how to run the class as an application or service and how to call the elements of that running class in other programs.

Comment: 1. That *"class definition"*... isn't. 2. Why don't you expose a single instance of the class, and import the instance?

Comment: because if i initialize camera twice it stucks. when camera is initialized once than it is unable to use in another porgram. thats y i want such a class which is urnning

Comment: ...what?! Could you give a [mcve] that *actually runs* and recreates the issue? And why would you expect `__init__` to not get called, have you read the [appropriate docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)?

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://gist.github.com/textbook/b08d61b9d7222c8553d1 for how I'd expect a singleton to work; `__init__` gets called if `__new__` returns an instance, whether or not it's new.

Comment: dear i dont want singleton i just want a class service which will run independently and i will call the elements of that class from that service. is there any way?????

Comment: So what is a *"class service"* and why are you talking about singletons? This question is very difficult to answer if you don't make it clear what the problem is.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "call from other program". Do you want to run multi-threaded or do you wish to expose some data from one program to others (as in a server-client architecture)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create only one instance and then import it in other programs.

Camera.py:

```
class Camera():
    def __init__(self):
        print "__instance created"

    def someFunc(self):
        print "Cool stuff here!"

c1 = Camera()
```

file2.py:

```
import Camera

c2 = Camera.c1
```

To call methods use `c2.someFunc()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited already. It was meant to be an example of calling methods.

Comment: no this method is not working. when i call it from other program it create new instance every time

Comment: @Engr How do you call it? I have the same instance.

Comment: __instance created
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python_Programming\Projects\singleton1.py", line 3, in <module>
    cam = Camera.c1
AttributeError: type object 'Camera' has no attribute 'c1'

Comment: Obviously you use some another method. And I asked "how do you call it", not "what error do you get".

Comment: @Engr again, provide a [mcve]. Code is unreadable in comments.